# how to use jquery widgets for submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have two jquery problems. 1. when i'm trying to apply a theme over a submit button - it's not working. i guess using .ui-button for submit is worng.

.uiTooltip problem - when i hover the empty fields , for the tooltip to appears - i get the tooltip title at left corner of the page....

```
$(function() {
$( document ).tooltip();
```

});

```
.ui-tooltip {





/* outline radius for mozilla/firefox only */
-moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;

background:#555555;
padding: 10px;
padding-top:3px;
position: absolute;
height:10px;
max-width: 300px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #aaa;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #aaa;
color:#FF9900;
border: 1px solid white;
```

Comment: show html for tooltips and submit buttons please

Comment: here is the complete code...can't put a link in the main post...https://www.dropbox.com/s/d5i6r32ag5tgewt/Landing%20Page.rar

Comment: <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"  />

Comment: sorry for the mistype - rough day

Comment: also for future reference, nobody will ever download a rar from dropbox to look at your code.. use jsfiddle.net/codepen.io or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the .ui-button class to the button if you want to apply the style:

```
<input class="ui-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
```

the .tooltip() function is not meant to be applied to the entire document. that is why the positioning is off. you need to apply the tooltip to the elements you wish to tip. for example, if you wanted to tip the submit button above you could use

```
$(function() {
    $( ".ui-button" ).tooltip();
});
```

because the selector for the tooltip is set to use a class from the button. I like to apply a general class to everything I want to tooltip and hit them all in one declaration:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".my-tooltip" ).tooltip();
});

<a href="#" class="my-tooltip" title="the tooltip">link</a>
<span class="my-tooltip" title="the tooltip">hover</span>
...
```

Comment: Juventus18 - Thanks for the tips - i'm newbie here  http://jsbin.com/qehima/1/watch?html,css,js,output

Comment: ok thats fine, the code i posted should work for you. you're still not getting a style on the button because there is no `.ui-button` CSS declared.

Comment: look in the CSS column of the pastebin... you never declare any styles for `.ui-button`. therefore, no styles will be applied

Comment: Sorry - still didn't get it - suppose i'm want my button to looks like in teh following link -http://jqueryui.com/button/ - how can it be done?

Comment: add this to your HTML file somewhere in the `<head></head>` tag: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">` it will load all of the jqueryUI styles for you

Comment: THANKS!!!! WORKING !!!  about the tooltip problem - as you can see, when i hover the fields - i get the title in the left corner also..... wonder why.... thanks again !

Comment: OK - the problem is gone after i set a font size... THANKS A MILLIONS!